# How to use cat to combine files in Makefile?

Tags: make, cat

First of all, I am not at all sure whether this is the correct place to ask a question like this but...

I am currently working on a directory and trying to create a file which would contain all of the contents of the files of the directory. The requirement is that I have to do this by using a rule in a Makefile. Currently, my makefile has a list of the files at the top, then a few other rules and then my sad attempt of a rule. The issue I'm running into is that I constantly get the "no rule to make target x needed by y". I think the issue is with either my recipe or my prerequisites. So:

```
FILES= file1 file2 file3 file4 file5...

directory_name/all.txt: **HERE IS THE PART IDK ABOUT**
   cat $^ > $@
```

I'm very new to the make command and to coding in general for that matter, so it may be that this is a silly problem to have but still, I couldn't find any satisfying answers online elsewhere. I have been trying to either refer to the files via their directory (like directory_name/%.txt or something) or by just listing the files as the prerequisites but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 2):

Your rule could look like

```
directory_name/all.txt: $(FILES)
        cat $(FILES) > $@
```

This would provide maximum portability so that the rule would work with both GNU `make` and BSD `make` (which may not understand `$^`; you don't say which implementation you're using).  Note that the line with the `cat` command needs to be indented with a tab character.

Comment: It still keeps returning the error message "No rule to make target 'file 1', needed by directory_name/all.txt"

Comment: also, I'm using GNU

Comment: @hesse You have said nothing about a `file 1`. In your question, you have `file1`. You also don't say anything about whether the files you list in your `FILES` variable exists or not. If they don't exist, `make` would obviously have to have a rule describing how to create them. If there is no such rule, it complains, as you have shown.

Comment: The space character was a spelling mistake, my apologies. And the files already exist in a sub-directory of the directory where I have the Makefile, could that have an effect on the process?

Comment: @hesse You would have to use the path to each file in the assignment to `FILES`.

Answer (score 0):

The dependency list is just $(FILES).

Basically, that just expands the list named. So the target is remade if any of the files that contribute to its validity are newer that the target itself.

There is a shorthand that will wildcard files, if you have a pattern. For your example, probably just:

`FILES= file[1-9]`